# Routing with option params with ? and &

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing, angular-components

I'm trying to have a deep look at angular's route, without any success. What I'm trying to do is to catch every params inside the url using the angular's route.

So let's take as example this url:

```
http://localhost:4200/PUC/#/P3?MODE=P&USER=AE13356&PROJECT=00001&PROTOCOL=00002&VERSION=1
```

I'm trying to assign the params to some variables.

So what I've done (wrong) is this:

The route:

```
 RouterModule.forRoot(
      [
        { path: "", component: AppComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
      ],
    )
```

the component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(){
    let queryParams = this.route.snapshot.queryParams;
    const mode = queryParams['MODE'];

    console.log("ID > " + mode);
  }
}
```

But `queryParams` is always an empty object. What am I missing?

**EDIT**

using `location.href` I've got the whole url, can I use this way to do some logic on the data I get? Basically what I have to do is to load one component if `PROJECT` has a value, and another if `PROJECT` is not in the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snapshot doesn't give you the updated queryParams whenever they change. But there's a `queryParams` `BehaviorSubject` on the `ActivatedRoute` that gives you the updated query params.

You should be using `route.queryParams.subscribe` for that.

Now, I'm not sure how to handle that `#` in your URL. But without that, since you have PUC as a route and P3 as the child of it, your Route Config would look something like this:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  {
    path: 'PUC/:segment',
    component: PucComponent
  }
])
```

As for route `PIC`, we're loading the `PucComponent`, you should be reading the `queryParams` there

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-puc',
  templateUrl: './puc.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./puc.component.css']
})
export class PucComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.route.queryParams
      .subscribe(queryParams => console.log(queryParams));
  }

}
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-hash-strategy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) for your ref.

Comment: Sadly `mode` is still undefined

Comment: @JacopoSciampi, I'm not really sure about that `#` in your URL. But if that's not there, I've updated my answer for the same. I've read somewhere that generally older browsers add a `#` to your urls.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is to enclose the value of query parameters inside **" "**.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/PUC','P3']" [queryParams]="{key:'stringvalue'}">Click here</a>
```

Enclosing in **" "** is not necessary if the value of query parameter is a number.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/PUC','P3']" [queryParams]="{key:number}">Click here</a>
```

**app.moudle.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule,Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

const routes:Routes = [{
       path:'PUC/P3', component:HelloComponent
    }]
@NgModule({
  imports:[ BrowserModule,FormsModule ,RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{useHash:true})],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<a [routerLink]="['/PUC','P3']" [queryParams]="{ MODE: 'p', USER:'AE13356',PROJECT:00001,PROTOCOL:00002,VERSION:1}"> Click here</a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**hello.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hello',
  template: `<h2>Check Console for Output</h2>`,
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute){}
  ngOnInit(){
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe((query)=>{
      console.log(query);
      console.log("MODE",query['MODE']);//output MODE:p
    });
  }
}
```

You can also see the working solution [here in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ml7t6k)

Answer (score 1):

**Reading via subscriptions**

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-detail',
  templateUrl: 'user-detail.component.html'
})
export class UserDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    }

ngOnInit() {
    this.activeRoute.queryParams.subscribe(queryParams => {
        // do something with the query params
    });

    this.activeRoute.params.subscribe(routeParams => {
        this.loadUserDetail(routeParams.id);
    });
}
```

**Dirty way**

By nesting the subscribers as below:

```
ngOnInit() {
    // Nest them together and
    this.activeRoute.queryParams.subscribe(queryParams => {
        this.activeRoute.params.subscribe(routeParams => {
            this.loadUserDetail(routeParams.id, queryParams.type);
        });
    });
}
```

Or you might be tempted to write a varied version of this i.e. move these nested callbacks to a helper function and then pass it yet another callback accepting query and route parameters i.e.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.readUrlParams((routeParams, queryParams) => {
        this.loadUserDetail(routeParams.id, queryParams.type);
    });
}

readUrlParams(callback) {
    // Nest them together and
    this.activeRoute.queryParams.subscribe(queryParams => {
        this.activeRoute.params.subscribe(routeParams => {
            callback(routeParams, queryParams);
        });
    });
}
```

**Use RxJS**

RxJS is a really powerful library and you can do it in several different ways, but the one I like and find myself using the most is to use the combineLatest operator by using which we merge the route and query parameters and have a single observable giving us both in a single object. Here is how our updated example would look like

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

// Add the observable and combineLatest
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/combineLatest';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-detail',
  templateUrl: 'user-detail.component.html'
})
export class UserDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        // Combine them both into a single observable
        const urlParams = Observable.combineLatest(
          this.activatedRoute.params,
          this.activatedRoute.queryParams,
          (params, queryParams) => ({ ...params, ...queryParams})
        );

        // Subscribe to the single observable, giving us both
        urlParams.subscribe(routeParams => {
            // routeParams containing both the query and route params
            this.loadUserDetail(routeParams.id, routeParams.type);
        });
    }
}
```